# code page values

Tags: vb.net, codepages

apart from 1252 what other code page values can be used with getencoding() in vb.net?

System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).Getstring()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, any code page that's supported by your system. 437 is one of the old DOS code pages, for example, and 28591 is ISO-Latin-1.

Here's a [list of lists of code pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964653.aspx) from Microsoft, but you should use Encoding.GetEncodings to see what's available on your own machine. I suspect it's not comprehensive though - I'm pretty sure there's a code page for one of the EBCDIC encodings, and I can't see it listed there.

Generally though you should know what code page your incoming data is in, so you don't often need to know what other code pages are available.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  See [Encoding.GetEncodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx).